# Run powershell scripts remotely using PsExec to change MySQL ODBC settings in the registry

Tags: powershell, psexec

I am trying to run a powershell script using PsExec on bunch of computers.

```
PsExec64.exe -i \\comp-int-tst-03 -u domain\un.admin -p asdfqw /accepteula PowerShell ChangeODBCServer.ps1
```

This is the error I get

```
PowerShell exited on comp-int-tst-03 with error code 1.
```

This is the script

```
if(Test-Path HKLM:\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBC.INI\user){
Set-Location HKLM:\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBC.INI\user
$server = (Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBC.INI\user).SERVER
if($server-eq "user"){
Set-ItemProperty . SERVER "user.app"
"Set1"}
}
if(Test-Path HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\ODBC\ODBC.INI\user){
Set-Location HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\ODBC\ODBC.INI\user
$server = (Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\ODBC\ODBC.INI\user).SERVER
if($server-eq "user"){
Set-ItemProperty . SERVER "user.app"
"Set2"}
}
```

Is there a way to get it going? Or to at least see why its not working? The script runs fine locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok So just tried this and that works fine. pc-host is the machine that I am trying to run it from. And C$ is the local disk that I can access as an admin share.

```
PsExec64.exe \\comp-int-tst-03 -u crc\un.admin -p asdfqw /accepteula PowerShell -noninteractive -File \\pc-host\C$\Users\u.name\ChangeODBCServer.ps1
```